# If-clause type 3 using "would", not "would have"?

Tags: conditionals, clauses

I saw in a movie that they said: "If this thing hadn't happened, I'd have $100"

I think the correct tense must be: "I'd have had $100"

is it informal usage?

Comment: You have been misled by the ESL courses which teach that only three types of conditionals in English are possible. This is ***wrong***. The conditional sentence above is perfectly grammatical, and the reason it doesn't match the conditionals you've been taught is that the first clause is set in the past, and the second is set in the (unreal) present.

Comment: This is a mixed conditional type very common in most, if not all, European languages.

Comment: Both variants are grammatical. But the meanings are not identical.